Lazy, linearized Cuts requiring the introduction of aux. variables
I'm solving a MIP using lazy/combinatorial Benders cut generation and am looking for some further guidance.
To improve my initial approach, I developed an alternative decomposition that simplifies the original model and strengthens the added cuts. This new structure, however, requires not only adding cuts in callbacks but also introducing new variables. This is due to the cuts being non-linear in nature, involving multiple logical disjunctions.
I began with an implementation using delayed cut generation: solving the MIP to optimality, adding necessary variables and cuts, and then re-optimizing. This method worked 'ok' with some warm-starting and tweaks. Now, I’m attempting a lazy approach within a single branch-and-bound tree. However, from what I’ve found, adding variables dynamically within the B&B process isn't possible (at least in Gurobi?).
To work around this, I’ve tried estimating a reasonable upper bound for the required variables, adding them at the start (and ensuring they are not removed during presolve), and then only activating them as cuts are introduced at infeasible integer nodes. This workaround has been somewhat effective on smaller test cases, but estimating the number of variables needed remains challenging in general.

Am I overcomplicating things with this approach? Is there a simpler or more streamlined way to do the same?

Additionally, this is basically some kind of column generation. Can I make use of techniques in the existing literature to improve my approach?



Can you add your cuts using Gurobi's support for indicator constraints and disjunctions, without new variables?

Does not seem like it.
https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4410512476817/comments/22756023633553

It is currently not possible to add an indicator constraint as a user cut or lazy constraint.

They instead suggest a delayed cut generation or to initialize the variables ahead, exactly as I initially thought of.
Are you aware of any frameworks/solvers that allow to lazily add such constraints?

None come to mind. There are frameworks for branch-price-and-cut, but I doubt they could be used to generate cuts in a callback. (Disclaimer: I've never actually worked with BPC, and I'm hoping to keep that streak intact.)
